how can I create a dashed line with two color grey and light grey
I want to create a dashed line like the image below using only CSS and HTML with minimal code. The distribution percent of dashes between two color may vary depending on another CSS variable, so I should be able to set a (percent of grey) and (100%—(percent of grey)) for light grey. I also want to be able to set the width and height of dashes and the width of gaps between them.

And no matter how much I try repeat(), grid, etc, I can not achieve this.
I also read these two but could not make changes to fit my needs:
How to create a dashed border with two alternating colours?
Gradient line with dashed pattern
Can you guys please help me to solve this challenge?
I tried using background-image,background-size,background-position, and background-repeat attributes with a combination of linear-gradient() and repeating-linear-gradient() functions, but I could not succeed in using them in any combination with different values.
I expect this


One idea is to use two linear gradient, one rendering the dashline, one splitting the 70% lighten percentage, and overlay them with the lighten blend-mode. All these can be extracted as a custom-property to control easily.


.dashed-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;

  --lighten-percentage: 70%;
  --dash-width: 18px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #ffff 0% 40%, #454f5b 40% 100%), linear-gradient(to right, #0000 0% round(down, var(--lighten-percentage), var(--dash-width)), #bbb round(down, var(--lighten-percentage), var(--dash-width)) 100%);
  background-size: var(--dash-width) 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
}
<div class="dashed-line"></div>




I would use mask and background. I am using red and blue for the demo but you can easily change with the colors you want


.line {
  height: 10px;
  /* adjust the 30px to control the size of the dash and the 50% to control the gap */
  mask: linear-gradient(90deg,#000 50%,#0000 0) 0/30px;
  /* adjust the 70% to control the percentage of red */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red 70%,blue 0);
}
<div class="line"></div>




@yahya I think this is way cleaner than my solution! It also allows transparent gaps. I was planning to update my solution to use mask instead but didn't got the time yesteray. You should use this solution instead. One can use round(70%,30px) to prevent the red percentage at the middle of a dash if needed. (Though round() is not widely supported in older browsers.)
